# Image not showing in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I'm currently having some troubles with an image showing in my WPF window. I can see it on the preview when coding, but it disappears when I'm in the program. The code in question is:

```
<Image Source="/images/c#.png" Height="50" Width="50" Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

Also, I've done some reading, and I've made sure the image is in my project resources, with the BuildAction set to Resource, so I have no idea what is wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Try setting build action to embedded resource and copy to output directory as always

Comment: Are you using this inside another control? Can you show us the full code?

Comment: Please ignore any "embedded resource" or "copy to output directory" advices. The image file should be in a folder named `images` in your Visual Studio project and its Build Action should be set to Resource. However, `c#.png` is not a valid image resource name, at least not at runtime.

Comment: Thank you for that Clemens, was not aware of that fact!

Comment: To be more precise, the fully expanded Pack URI `pack://application:,,,/images/c#.png` (which is created internally) is not valid due to the `#` character.